# How to generate sequence in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have created a sequence called as hibernate_sequnce using following command

```
create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 400;
```

This is my hibernate annotated dao

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_BIZ_TERM")
public class BizTerm implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3056055722354292136L;

    private Long bizTermId;
@Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column(name="BIZ_TERM_ID")
    public Long getBizTermId() {
        return bizTermId;
    }
    public void setBizTermId(Long bizTermId) {
        this.bizTermId = bizTermId;
    }
}
```

In order to insert new record into the table hibernate is generating wrong query to get next sequence value..
Hibernate is always issuing this query..no matter what I do..

```
select nextval(hibernate_sequnce)
```

I am using oracle 10G which is reporting following error always..

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

The query issued should be `select hibernate_sequnce.nextval from dual;`
what to do now, am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something like this for Oracle sequences.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "BIZ_TERM_ID")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "myKeySeq", sequenceName = "hibernate_sequence ", allocationSize = 20)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "myKeySeq")
private Long bizTermId;;
```

I'd name the sequence better than hibernate_sequence though.  try something like biz_term_sequence.  You will want different sequences per table primary key.

Comment: also as Mulmoth suggested, ensure your dialect is set!

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure the Oracle dialect?

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
```